# Get RAM system size

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, ram

I would like to know how can I get the size of my RAM through C++ (on Windows 7).

Answer (score 11):

Use [`GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300158(v=VS.85).aspx) to retrieve the amount of RAM that is **physically installed** on the computer.

(Note that this requires Windows Vista SP1 or later. The function is not available on earlier versions of the Windows operating system.)

The [remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300158(v=VS.85).aspx) on MSDN say:

> The GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory
>   function retrieves the amount of
>   physically installed RAM from the
>   computer's SMBIOS firmware tables.
>   **This can differ from the amount
>   reported by the GlobalMemoryStatusEx
>   function, which sets the ullTotalPhys
>   member of the MEMORYSTATUSEX structure
>   to the amount of physical memory that
>   is available for the operating system
>   to use**. The amount of memory available
>   to the operating system can be less
>   than the amount of memory physically
>   installed in the computer because the
>   BIOS and some drivers may reserve
>   memory as I/O regions for
>   memory-mapped devices, making the
>   memory unavailable to the operating
>   system and applications.
>
> **The amount of physical memory
>   retrieved by the
>   GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory
>   function must be equal to or greater
>   than the amount reported by the
>   GlobalMemoryStatusEx function;** if it
>   is less, the SMBIOS data is malformed
>   and the function fails with
>   ERROR_INVALID_DATA. Malformed SMBIOS
>   data may indicate a problem with the
>   user's computer.

That means, you would also want to look at [`GlobalMemoryStatusEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589(v=VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 7):

Okay, guys! I've found the solution by doing this like that [guru mode on]:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT  0x0501 // I misunderstand that
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;

   statex.dwLength = sizeof (statex); // I misunderstand that

   GlobalMemoryStatusEx (&statex);
   cout << "Physical RAM => " << (float)statex.ullTotalPhys/(1024*1024*1024)<< endl;

   system("PAUSE");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I had to define _WIN32_WINNT  0x0501, but i don't know why [guru mode is off].

If somebody could explain me what it is doing and why it doesn't work without it.

One more thing, what is that:

```
statex.dwLength = sizeof (statex);
```

Comment: For more information on _WIN32_WINNT read the Microsoft Developer Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt

Answer (score 5):

On Windows:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PGMSE)(LPMEMORYSTATUSEX);
PGMSE pGMSE = (PGMSE) GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandle( TEXT( "kernel32.dll" ) ), TEXT( "GlobalMemoryStatusEx") );
if ( pGMSE != 0 )
{
    MEMORYSTATUSEX mi;
    memset( &mi, 0, sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX) );
    mi.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);
    if ( pGMSE( &mi ) == TRUE )
        os << "RAM: " << mi.ullTotalPhys / 1048576 << "MB";
    else
        pGMSE = 0;
}
if ( pGMSE == 0 )
{
    MEMORYSTATUS mi;
    memset( &mi, 0, sizeof(MEMORYSTATUS) );
    mi.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUS);
    GlobalMemoryStatus( &mi );
    os << "RAM: " << mi.dwTotalPhys / 1048576 << "MB";
}
```

On Linux:

Read `/proc/meminfo`.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the [`GlobalMemoryStatusEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which returns a [`MEMORYSTATUSEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366770%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The field you want is called `ullTotalPhys`.

Answer (score 1):

The `0x501` is the WindowsXP version, i.e. the `MEMORYSTATUSEX` struct is not supported by some older Windows versions. Your windef.h probably points to a lower `WINVER` than `0x5XX`.